# Downgrading Cuda version only in specific environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, cudatoolkit

Is it possible to downgrade Cudatoolkit in a specific conda environment? I have Cuda 11.8 in my base environment but due to some dependencies, I want to downgrade it in a specific conda environment to make it work with other packages in that environment.